# My function is not reading data from the input file properly (C)

Tags: c, linux

I am having trouble with the ReadPersonData function. I need to read in data from a and store the data in structure arrays.

Data looks like this: Name, Country, City, Street, Hobby count, Hobbies

```
John Brazil Brasilia Esplanada 1 Reading

Mary Japan Tokyo Harajuku 2 Painting Swimming

David Australia Canberra Northbourne 3 Running Gardening Cycling

Sarah Norway Oslo Storgata 2 Cooking Fishing Writing Dancing

James Mexico Tijuana Insurgentes 5 Reading Painting Running Swimming Cycling

Jennifer Egypt Cairo Ramses 6 Cooking Painting Dancing Swimming Reading Writing

Michael Canada Ottawa Wellington 7 Running Fishing Cycling Reading Painting Writing Swimming

Jessica Estonia Tallinn Keskuse 8 Cooking Dancing Reading Painting Swimming Running Writing Gardening

Robert Argentina Rosario Corrientes 9 Running Cycling Reading Swimming Painting Writing Fishing Cooking Dancing

Amanda Germany Berlin Alexanderplatz 10 Reading Painting Running Swimming Gardening Cooking Fishing Cycling Writing Dancing
```

I am having trouble reading in the hobbies. It will read in the hobbies until the hobby count goes from 3 to 2, then it stops reading in data, probably because in the cycle
`for(i = 0; i < personList[persons.hobbyCount; i++)` , i is now bigger than a persons hobby count. I want it to keep on reading data, but I just can't figure it out.
Since English is not my first language I don't know how to search for solutions on this particular topic and ChatGPT is not helping so now here I am. How do I fix my problem?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LEN 32
#define MIN_HOBBIES 0
#define MAX_HOBBIES 10
#define MAX_PERSONS 100
#define MAX_FILE_NAME_SIZE 16

#define ARG_CNT 2
#define ARG_EXEC_NAME argv[0]
#define ARG_FILE_NAME argv[1]

typedef struct
{
  char country[MAX_NAME_LEN];
  char city[MAX_NAME_LEN];
  char street[MAX_NAME_LEN];

} address;

typedef struct
{
  char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
  address residence;
  int hobbyCount;
  char hobbies[MAX_HOBBIES][MAX_NAME_LEN];

} person;

int ReadPersonData(person personList[] , int limit, char *fName);
void FindSameHobby(person personList[], int personCount, char hobbyName[]);
void OutPutData(person personList[], int personCount, char hobbyName[]);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if(argc != ARG_CNT)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s input_file\n", ARG_EXEC_NAME);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  person personList[MAX_PERSONS];

  int personCount = ReadPersonData(personList, MAX_PERSONS, ARG_FILE_NAME);


  return 0;
}

int ReadPersonData(person personList[] , int limit, char *fName)
{

  int persons = 0;
  int i;

  FILE *fPerson = fopen(fName, "r");
  if(fPerson == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening input file %s", fName);
    perror(" ");
    return persons;
  }

  while(fscanf(fPerson, "%s %s %s %s %d", personList[persons].name,
                                          personList[persons].residence.country,
                                          personList[persons].residence.city,
                                          personList[persons].residence.street,
                                         &personList[persons].hobbyCount) == 5)

  {

    if(personList[persons].hobbyCount < MIN_HOBBIES ||
    personList[persons].hobbyCount > MAX_HOBBIES)
      {
        printf("ERROR! Invalid hobby count for %s, exiting now!\n",
        personList[persons].name);
        exit(1);
      }

   for(i = 0; i < personList[persons].hobbyCount; i++)
   {
     fscanf(fPerson, "%s", personList[persons].hobbies[i]);
   }

    persons++;

   if(persons > limit)
   {
     fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! Input file is too long! ALlowed "
                        "limit is %d entries. Reading of the "
                        "file has stopped, continuing within "
                        "a partial dataset\n", limit);
     break;
   }
  }

fclose(fPerson);

return persons;

}
```

I tried to change the cycle parameters to no avail.

Comment: `Sarah Norway Oslo Storgata 2 Cooking Fishing Writing Dancing` this line has 4 hobbies while it says it has only 2 hobbies (or has 2 extra data after 2 hobbies). `fscanf` is not good at reading data like this. One possible strategy is reading whole lines via `fgets` and parsing the lines.

Comment: You can't reliably do `fopen(...); fprintf(...); perror`.  You have to call `perror` after `fopen` without any intervening calls that may modify `errno`, and `fprintf` may modify errno.  You can do `fopen(...); fprintf("...", strerror(errno)`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line has 2 extra data after 2 hobbies:

```
Sarah Norway Oslo Storgata 2 Cooking Fishing Writing Dancing
```

Therefore, after reading the hobbies (`Cooking Fishing`), your program will behave as if the data left is added before the next line and the next line is :

```
Writing Dancing James Mexico Tijuana Insurgentes 5 Reading Painting Running Swimming Cycling
```

Then the format specifier `%d` won't accept the non-integer input `Tijuana` and reading stops.

One way for fixing this is skipping the extra data after hobbies like this:

```c
   for(i = 0; i < personList[persons].hobbyCount; i++)
   {
     fscanf(fPerson, "%s", personList[persons].hobbies[i]);
   }

   // add this to skip until the end of line
   int c;
   while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

    persons++;
```

Note that this way doesn't support cases where data after the hobby count is *less than* the hobby count or lines has other issues. To support these cases, you should use other ways like reading whole lines via `fgets` and parsing the lines (using `strtok`, for example).

Answer (score 0):

A few issues ...

1. The lines don't have a fixed number of tokens
2. Some of the hobby counts *can* be *wrong*, we can't use `fscanf`. (e.g.) Some lines specify a hobby count that is smaller than the number of hobbies on the line.
3. Better to use `fgets`, and `strtok`.
4. Calling `fprintf` before `perror` produces incorrect results for an `fopen` failure. Reverse the order of the calls.
5. Doing `personList[persons].name` (e.g.) everywhere is verbose and error prone. Better to use a pointer to the current person record (e.g. `per->name`).

---

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LEN 32
#define MIN_HOBBIES 0
#define MAX_HOBBIES 10
#define MAX_PERSONS 100
#define MAX_FILE_NAME_SIZE 16

#define ARG_CNT 2
#define ARG_EXEC_NAME argv[0]
#define ARG_FILE_NAME argv[1]

typedef struct {
    char country[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    char city[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    char street[MAX_NAME_LEN];
} address;

typedef struct {
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    address residence;
    int hobbyCount;
    char hobbies[MAX_HOBBIES][MAX_NAME_LEN];

} person;

int ReadPersonData(person personList[], int limit, char *fName);
void FindSameHobby(person personList[], int personCount, char hobbyName[]);
void OutPutData(person personList[], int personCount, char hobbyName[]);

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != ARG_CNT) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s input_file\n", ARG_EXEC_NAME);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    person personList[MAX_PERSONS];

    int personCount = ReadPersonData(personList, MAX_PERSONS, ARG_FILE_NAME);

    return 0;
}

int
ReadPersonData(person personList[], int limit, char *fName)
{

    int persons = 0;
    int i;
    char buf[1000];

    FILE *fPerson = fopen(fName, "r");

    if (fPerson == NULL) {
// NOTE/BUG: to catch the error from fopen, perror must be first
#if 0
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening input file %s", fName);
        perror(" ");
#else
        perror(fName);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening input file %s", fName);
#endif
        return persons;
    }

// NOTE/BUG: because we have a variable number of tokens and some hobby counts
// are wrong, we can't use *scanf
    // read in all lines
    while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fPerson) != NULL) {
        // get the name
        char *tok = strtok(buf," \n");

        // handle blank line
        if (tok == NULL)
            continue;

        // point to the correct person record
        person *per = &personList[persons];

        // save the name
        strcpy(per->name,tok);

        // get country, city, street ...
        tok = strtok(NULL," \n");
        strcpy(per->residence.country,tok);

        tok = strtok(NULL," \n");
        strcpy(per->residence.city,tok);

        tok = strtok(NULL," \n");
        strcpy(per->residence.street,tok);

        // get the hobby count
        tok = strtok(NULL," \n");
        per->hobbyCount = atoi(tok);

        // check the specified hobby count against the hard limits
        if (per->hobbyCount < MIN_HOBBIES || per->hobbyCount > MAX_HOBBIES) {
            printf("ERROR! Invalid hobby count for %s, exiting now!\n",
                per->name);
            exit(1);
        }

        // some lines have more hobbies than the count specified
        // is this bad data?
        // just accept more than the count up to the hard limit
        for (i = 0;  ; i++) {
            tok = strtok(NULL," \n");
            if (tok == NULL)
                break;

            if (i >= MAX_HOBBIES) {
                printf("ERROR! Too many hobbies for %s, exiting now!\n",
                    per->name);
                exit(1);
            }

            strcpy(per->hobbies[i],tok);
        }

        // hobby count doesn't always match number of hobbies on the line
        // correct the hobby count to number we found
        if (i > per->hobbyCount) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Name %s hobby count is %d but found %d hobbies\n",
                per->name,per->hobbyCount,i);
            per->hobbyCount = i;
        }

        persons++;

        if (persons > limit) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! Input file is too long! ALlowed "
                "limit is %d entries. Reading of the "
                "file has stopped, continuing within "
                "a partial dataset\n", limit);
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(fPerson);

    return persons;
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

---

Here is the program output for your sample input:

```
Name Sarah hobby count is 2 but found 4 hobbies
```